# Task "default" not found - uglify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, command, line

I'm taking my first steps with Grunt, however I'm getting to following error when trying to minify my JS file:

```
"Task "default" not found"
```

I've checked previous similar answers but to no avail. The Gruntfile code is below, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {   
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/libs/*.js' //
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            }
        }

        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: 'js/build/production.js',
                dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `grunt.initConfig` object. You need to place a comma after the closing brace of your `concat` entry:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {   
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'js/libs/*.js' //
                ],
                dest: 'js/build/production.js',
            } 
        },   // <-- missing comma was here

        uglify: {
            build: {
                src: 'js/build/production.js',
                dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

This syntax error causes Grunt to never see your `grunt.registerTask('default')` call.